# SqlDataReader.GetValue not successful for geometry columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial

When I have a SqlDataReader on a table where the geometry type is used, `reader.GetFieldType(index)` returns null and `reader.GetValue(index)` results in

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
> located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

I tried to add the nuget package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types v14.0.1016.290, but that does not remedy the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `geometry` type yet, just read documentation. The [`geometry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry?view=sql-dacfx-150) represents a point in a coordinate system, it is stored as binary. So try this:

```
SqlGeometry geometry = new SqlGeometry();
geometry.Read(new BinaryReader(reader.GetSqlBytes(index).Stream));
```

Comment: Interesting. How can I know it's the type `geometry`?

Comment: @AndersLindén: not at all since the documentation simply doesn't mention it. You have to download and install the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package from nuget.